# VSTS Load Test : Unable to stop running .css file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, performance-testing

I did NOT see below request in my webtest, however it is being executed and failing.

I know this is a coding issue and it has to be fixed by development team , however I want to skip running this request for now and make my test pass. Please help me.

GTE https://www.corteva.com/etc/designs/default.css

Webtest:

[image]
Results:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find a dependent request in webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951947/cannot-find-a-dependent-request-in-webtest)

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Parse Dependant Requests to false for corresponding request (e.g.  `https://www.corteva.com`).

[Ignore unimportant errors in web test](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f8c641b-9d52-4886-974c-542687c20556/ignore-unimportant-errors-in-web-test?forum=vstswebtest)